# extend class with different import

Tags: java

I have a class like this:

```
import a.DBManager
class A{
    public Connection connection;
    Connection getConnection(){
       this.connection = DBManager.getInstance().getConnection();
    }
}
```

I want to extend this class like this:

```
import a.MyDBManager
class B extends A{
    
}
```

What I want in "Class B" is that it uses "MYDBManager" in all of the inherited methods automatically for getting the connection and rest of the code I don't need to change.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, no.

Define and use a method override to initialize a different manager instance, or pass through a different instance through the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You could simply re-assign the `connection` instance variable from the constructor of the subclass and then that will be used by both methods inherited from class A and those defined in class B. This is because the assignment in your subclass will be called after your superclass constructor and therefore it will overwrite the value assigned in your superclass to the `connection` instance variable.

So in class A, your code could be like,

```
import a.DBManager;
class A{
    public Connection connection;
    public A() {
        this.connection = DBManager.getInstance().getConnection();
    }
}
```

and in class B

```
import a.MyDBManager
class B extends A{
    public B(){
        super()
        this.connection = MyDBManager.getInstance().getConnection(); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you. If it did, I would very much appreciate it if you would mark my answer as "Accepted". Good day to you!

Comment: this.connection is not used anywhere. (I know its a poor programming,can't change it  since its a legacy code), it uses MyDBManager.getInstance().getConnection();  directly in every method.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the get connection method of class B.

```
    public class B extends A {
      public Connection connection;
      @Override
      getConnection(){
        this.connection = MyDBManager.getInstance().getConnection();
      }
    }
```

This is possible when Connection refers to an interface that your MyDBManager.getInstance().getConnection() returns,

Or it is possible when your MyDBManager.getInstance().getConnection() returns an an object that is a subclass of Connection.